# Laravel cannot validate field against custom date format

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5.6

I am having a date format like this `30 Mar, 2018`.

if i apply this `'start_date' => 'required|date` validation rule, then `The start date is not a valid date.` error message is showing.

I have this code in model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class Rates extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    //protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';

    protected $dates = [
        'start_date',
        'end_date'
    ];


    public function setStartDateAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['start_date'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d M, Y',$value);
    }

    public function setEndDateAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['end_date'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d M, Y',$value);
    }

}
```

For date input i am having,

```
<input class="form-control form_datetime_start valid" placeholder="Enter Start Date" name="start_date" type="text" value="30 Mar, 2018" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
```

Even i tried to add this `date_format:d M, Y` rule, it also show `The start date does not match the format d M.` it is not considering `,` and `Y`.

Where do i miss? whats the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can supply a custom format for validation, as you have tried:

`date_format:format`

However you need to escape the comma, because that's the rule parameter separator, using quotes `"d M, Y"`

Full rule set for your field:

`'start_date' => 'required|date_format:"d M, Y"'`

Remember it's stated in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-date-format) that:

> **date_format:format**
>
> The field under validation must match the given format. You should use **either** date or  date_format when validating a field, not both.